# How to Force Button Action Immediately

Tags: angularjs, http

So I'm not sure if there is truly a way to make this happen.

Basically I have an angular app with a nodejs backend that shows longrunning queries on our production environment.  This is set on an interval to refresh this info every 20 seconds.  The issue is this:

Buttons on the page, if clicked when a refresh is occurring, will not fire off.  They have to wait until the whole stream of calls to refresh the data have finished, and even then sometimes, they do not fire.

If I happen to catch it while no refresh is occurring, the button works as expected.

Is there a way to force this action to take precedence over the refresh so it occurs immediately even if there are other processes occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: You should post some more details, your question is not very answerable like this. Are you perhaps exhausting the amount of concurrent AJAX connections your browser supports?

Comment: My apologies.  I am making a call on page load that gets an array of all of our database instances.  I then have an interval set up to loop through these and query them for longrunning queries.  So this ends  up with a large number of calls being sent every 20 seconds.  In the Network tab of dev tools, I see the large list of calls for the refresh pending and being resolved.  When I click the button, this call simply gets added to the end of that list and waits on them.  Is this an issue with the Node server not being able to process it yet? or a bottleneck on the front end?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification in your comments, it sounds like you're hitting your browser's limit on how many connections can be made to any given hostname. Look at the `Connections per Hostname` column [here](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network).

To fix this, send less calls at once. For example, you could implement your own queuing system for your refresh-related calls, instead of firing them off all at once, leaving plenty of connections open for other requests (like your button).